# A special presheaf of rings over the spectra $ \mathrm{Spec} A $.

Tags: sheaf-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $ A $ be a commutative ring with unity, and $ \mathrm{Spec} A $ the spectra of $ A $.

We define over $ \mathrm{Spec} A $ the presheaf of rings as follows :

If $ U $ is an open subset of $ \mathrm{Spec} A $, let put : $ S(U) = \{ \ a \in A \ | \ a \not \in \mathfrak{p} \ , \ \forall \mathfrak{p} \in U \ \} $ and, $ \mathcal{F} (U) = S (U)^{-1} A $.

If : $ V \subset U $, we take as the restriction morphism, the canonical morphism : $ S (U)^{-1} A \to S (V)^{-1} A $.

My questions are :

1) Why does : $ \mathcal{F}_x = A_{ \mathfrak{p} } $ such that $ x $ are the corresponding point of the ideal : $ \mathfrak{p} \in \mathrm{Spec} A $ ?.

2) Why does : $ S ( \mathrm{Spec} A ) ^{-1} A = ( A^* )^{-1} A $ ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is $A^*$? I first thought you meant the units of $A$, but that meaning gives the obvious $(A^*)^{-1}A\cong A$. That said, if $A^*$ is the units, then (2) is because every non-unit is an element of some maximal ideal, and thus a prime ideal, so the only elements not in any prime ideal are the units.)

Comment: Thank you. $ (A^* )^{-1} A = Q(A) $ ( a field of fractions of $ A $ ), no ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by $A^*$, which was hy I asked the question.

Comment: Sorry, Yes, in my book, it's said that : $ (A^* )^{-1} A \simeq A $ as you said.  :-)